# Sendmail Partial Delivery On Some Emails

Tags: debian, email, sendmail, dkim

I have three mail users. Each successfully send and receive mail.

There is a single repeated problem email, a *Web Form Notification* sent from an Amazon server which is sent to all three mail users. Sendmail receives for one user and skips the other two. This problem has occurred only on this *Web Form Notification* mail from Amazon. I sent *My Own Test Notification* which was successfully received in all three mail boxes. See mail headers and mail.out logs below.

**Question**

Why did the *Web Form Notification* deliver to only one user while *My Own Test Notification* delivered to all three?

**Web Form Notification - Header**

```
From 01010187719db599-3ea881ca-830d-4456-8616-e6b9369fc482-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com Tue Apr 11 14:39:18 2023
Received: from a59-138.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com (a59-138.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com [54.240.59.138])
    by mailserv12.mydomain.net (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTP id 33BIdGDV003061
    for <coltonr@theclient123.com>; Tue, 11 Apr 2023 14:39:18 -0400
Authentication-Results: mailserv12.mydomain.net;
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=scorpioncontact.com header.i=@scorpioncontact.com header.b="ME+v6RKl";
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=amazonses.com header.i=@amazonses.com header.b="ipmPqQyJ";
    dkim-atps=neutral
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=zyd7bhcyyv6pkbmskjzvey56uuwqxgpn; d=scorpioncontact.com;
    t=1681238373;
    h=MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Message-ID;
    bh=bL3BFSeLE3chpj5/RvpeTn3+6Rv+aL2Z+ABDaa7iqj4=;
    b=ME+v6RKlhmYjhcAtszGjmpPrxm+6YacRKVrMCEht7fhrDER7LJFV+QaWRTYLrge0
    fRGzSPMk+JRE5adZwup7Q/8KkC+sfgfS73k23g/I5aLV96N/OmzlQ9WrMTYW2D2WNRQ
    O/1e3Lp06sZkBrZjyiRYdgfrnApl7cMriOmRucOA=
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=hsbnp7p3ensaochzwyq5wwmceodymuwv; d=amazonses.com; t=1681238373;
    h=MIME-Version:From:To:Date:Subject:Content-Type:Message-ID:Feedback-ID;
    bh=bL3BFSeLE3chpj5/RvpeTn3+6Rv+aL2Z+ABDaa7iqj4=;
    b=ipmPqQyJ5S3cp8TU9NIY3zehs/C/K0yE1vzNxj1hpHgHjXNq9WxfSPQHTURZqmS8
    m641YaijPHHTy9s3zL0A95b/hvFbrU0f4I8WbluGokATkqBMJsheleoXce8q1EgWFbP
    vzkVhPw9LEbGsmxnxA3HnFWvs1+bkzTfL+bQ+nyI=
x-scorpion-express-id: 65b8c774-1516-42d6-8c91-834020b9bfdb
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "Scorpion Elite Marketing Team" <e@scorpioncontact.com>
To: useraaa@theclient123.com, info@theclient123.com, userbbb@theclient123.com,
        miscuser@scorpion.co
Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2023 18:39:33 +0000
Subject: New Contact Form Submitted on theclient123.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary=--boundary_90037_299c72a4-1788-46f2-844e-daf4efca6e0b
Message-ID: <01010187719db599-3ea881ca-830d-4456-8616-e6b9369fc482-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>
Feedback-ID: 1.us-west-2.eicjSNBV8JhWOJqg0ogtPl1jzTlcz4eUD2AseGUjcbE=:AmazonSES
X-SES-Outgoing: 2023.04.11-54.240.59.138


----boundary_90037_299c72a4-1788-46f2-844e-daf4efca6e0b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
....................
```

**Web Form Notification - Mail.Out Logs**

```
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 sm-mta[3061]: 33BIdGDV003061: from=<01010187719db599-3ea881ca-830d-4456-8616-e6b9369fc482-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>, size=47680, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<01010187719db599-3ea881ca-830d-4456-8616-e6b9369fc482-000000@us-west-2.amazonses.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=a59-138.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com [54.240.59.138]
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BIdGDV003061: a59-138.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com [54.240.59.138] not internal
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BIdGDV003061: not authenticated
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BIdGDV003061: message has signatures from scorpioncontact.com, amazonses.com
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BIdGDV003061: DKIM verification successful
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BIdGDV003061: s=zyd7bhcyyv6pkbmskjzvey56uuwqxgpn d=scorpioncontact.com SSL 
Apr 11 14:39:18 mailserv12 sm-mta[3061]: 33BIdGDV003061: Milter insert (1): header: Authentication-Results:  mailserv12.mydomain.net;\n\tdkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=scorpioncontact.com header.i=@scorpioncontact.com header.b="ME+v6RKl";\n\tdkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=amazonses.com header.i=@amazonses.com header.b="ipmPqQyJ";\n\tdkim-atps=neutral
Apr 11 14:39:19 mailserv12 sm-mta[3128]: 33BIdGDV003061: to=|/home/project/theclient123.com/mail_receiver/symbolic_links/useraaa, ctladdr=<useraaa@theclient123.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=prog, pri=78253, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```

**My Own Test Notification - Header**

```
From me@thesecondclient.com Tue Apr 11 15:12:06 2023
Received: from mailserv16.mydomain.net (mailserv16 [108.174.96.236])
    by mailserv12.mydomain.net (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTP id 33BJC4jO030103;
    Tue, 11 Apr 2023 15:12:06 -0400
Authentication-Results: mailserv12.mydomain.net;
    dkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=thesecondclient.com header.i=@thesecondclient.com header.b="CRwy8b19";
    dkim-atps=neutral
Received: from mailserv16.mydomain.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mailserv16.mydomain.net (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTP id 33BJBh6x031483;
    Tue, 11 Apr 2023 15:11:43 -0400
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=thesecondclient.com;
    s=default; t=1681240303;
    bh=TyxDFFT2b9//OI2sxrmvqxdMhjAi1WsVntJyetPgHDk=;
    h=Date:From:To:Subject;
    b=CRwy8b19myhGZ74YsypoFmPG3SXBppaTo5MYRu3YvYS4DrNzcXWMHiCZZc7Z9Safc
     qBEiG+3h+VxooKP/HYWtUQI172gldANyn4N/+XSWB6hWec0/n3ZnlHdkbGXsEGazCW
     AkbS4GGYXbIAlQ9m19273P+mljIfR6FwxuGiGwcE=
Received: (from susan@localhost)
    by mailserv16.mydomain.net (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id 33BJBhus031481;
    Tue, 11 Apr 2023 15:11:43 -0400
Date: Tue, 11 Apr 2023 15:11:43 -0400
Message-Id: <202304111911.33BJBhus031481@mailserv16.mydomain.net>
X-Authentication-Warning: mailserv16.mydomain.net: susan set sender to me@thesecondclient.com using -f
From: me@thesecondclient.com
To: coltonr@theclient123.com, info@theclient123.com, belindas@theclient123.com,
        me@thesecondclient.com
Subject: Test
x-mailer: Tester
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="-------------PineappleCode0"

---------------PineappleCode0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

All the testing
---------------PineappleCode0--
```

**My Own Test Notification - Mail.Out Logs**

```
Apr 11 15:12:06 mailserv12 sm-mta[30103]: 33BJC4jO030103: from=<me@thesecondclient.com>, size=1284, class=0, nrcpts=3, msgid=<202304111911.33BJBhus031481@mailserv16.mydomain.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=mailserv16 [108.174.96.236]
Apr 11 15:12:06 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BJC4jO030103: no signing table match for 'me@thesecondclient.com'
Apr 11 15:12:06 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BJC4jO030103: DKIM verification successful
Apr 11 15:12:06 mailserv12 opendkim[20328]: 33BJC4jO030103: s=default d=thesecondclient.com SSL 
Apr 11 15:12:06 mailserv12 sm-mta[30103]: 33BJC4jO030103: Milter insert (1): header: Authentication-Results:  mailserv12.mydomain.net;\n\tdkim=pass (1024-bit key; unprotected) header.d=thesecondclient.com header.i=@thesecondclient.com header.b="CRwy8b19";\n\tdkim-atps=neutral
Apr 11 15:12:07 mailserv12 sm-mta[30189]: 33BJC4jO030103: to=|/home/project/theclient123.com/mail_receiver/symbolic_links/userbbb, ctladdr=<userbbb@theclient123.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=prog, pri=91664, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Apr 11 15:12:07 mailserv12 sm-mta[30189]: 33BJC4jO030103: to=|/home/project/theclient123.com/mail_receiver/symbolic_links/info, ctladdr=<info@theclient123.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=prog, pri=91664, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Apr 11 15:12:08 mailserv12 sm-mta[30189]: 33BJC4jO030103: to=|/home/project/theclient123.com/mail_receiver/symbolic_links/useraaa, ctladdr=<useraaa@theclient123.com> (8/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=prog, pri=91664, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
```